# Do we have to write OnItemTapped method in xml code behind page or ViewModel Page ? and How?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

i am trying to add below method in my ViewModel class but showing the error like method not found in code behind page so question is do i have to write the below method in xml code behind page or in viewmodel file , i want to follow MVVM Pattern

**ViewModel Page :**

```
public class StationPickerViewModel : ContentPage
    {
      //  private List<StationDetails> _stationDetails;

        public List<StationDetails> Stations
        {
            get
            {
              return  new List<StationDetails>() {
                    new StationDetails{ Id = 1, StationCode=01, StationFullName="vapi", StationShortName="vp", TrainId=1},
                    new StationDetails{ Id = 2, StationCode=02, StationFullName="KaramBele", StationShortName="kmb", TrainId=2},
                    new StationDetails{ Id = 3, StationCode=03, StationFullName="Bhilad", StationShortName="bh", TrainId=3},
                    new StationDetails{ Id = 4, StationCode=04, StationFullName="Sanjan", StationShortName="sn", TrainId=4},
                    new StationDetails{ Id = 5, StationCode=05, StationFullName="Umargam", StationShortName="um", TrainId=5}
            };
            }
        }

        public void OnItemTapped(object o, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var station = e.Item as StationDetails;
            DisplayAlert("Selection Mode", "You Tapped On" + station.StationFullName, "OK");
        }
    }
```

**xml Page Code :**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="RailwayIndicator.View.StationPickerPage">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout Padding="20">
                <Label FontSize="Large">Choose the Starting Station</Label>
                <ListView x:Name="StationList" 
                          ItemsSource="Binding Stations"
                          ItemTapped="OnItemTapped">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="Binding StationFullName" Font="12" BackgroundColor="Brown"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>

            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
```

**xml page code behind :**

```
namespace RailwayIndicator.View
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class StationPickerPage : ContentPage
    {
        public StationPickerPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have multiple issues with your code, for example your ViewModel is inheriting from `ContentPage` which does not makes any sense.

So please take a look at some MVVM samples out there.

If you want to use MVVM and still have "control" over those events in your ViewModel, you can use `EventToCommandBehavior`. More about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior) and [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/turn-events-into-commands-behaviors/).

Using `EventToCommandBehavior` you have the ability and nice way to bind events to some `Command` in your ViewModel, doing this you are migrating some more code logic from code-behind class which is an good way to respect MVVM even more.

I also recommend you to take a look at docs and learn more about implementing MVVM in your Xamarin.Forms app, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm).

Wishing you lots of luck with coding!

Comment: @Almur thank you for reply , apart from above is there any good link where i can get to familiar with all useful Technics .

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm